# Check the daily active users of each model

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have such table:

```
| server_time | ip         | model | user_id | version | event_id |
| ------------|----------- |-------|---------|---------|----------|
| 2018-07-01  | 113        | A83   | u1      | v1      | login    |
| 2018-07-01  | 114        | R11s  | u2      | v2      | login    |
| 2018-07-01  | 10         | R15   | u3      | v3      | login    |
| 2018-07-02  | 211        | R11s  | u2      | v4      | login    |
| 2018-08-12  | 123        | R15   | u3      | v5      | login    |
```

I have 6 columns server_time,ip,model,user_id,version,event_id
How to check the daily active users of each model ,including dates when no records were generated into the table.

What I have already tried is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM (event_id = login) THEN GROUP BY server_time;
```

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Comment: server_time|model|daily_active_users|

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can get the count of daily active users per model with:

```
select server_time, model, count(distinct user_id) as cnt
from mytable
where event_id = 'login'
```

If you want missing days, then an option uses a recursive cte:

```
with recursive cte as (
    seleect min(server_time) as dt, max(server_time) as max_dt from mytable
    union all
    select dt + interval 1 day from cte where dt < max_dt
)
select c.dt, count(distinct t.user_id) as cnt
from cte c
left join mytable t on t.server_time = c.dt
group by c.dt
```

Comment: why we use ip not user_id?

Comment: @YCCLLL: I think you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the recursive cte to create the date `cross join` it with distinct `model` and left join it with `your_table` as follows

```
with recursive cte as (
    select min(server_time) as dt, max(server_time) as max_dt from your_table t
    union all select dt + interval 1 day from cte t where dt < max_dt
)
select c.dt, m.model, count(distinct t.user_id) as cnt
  from cte c Cross join (select distinct model from your_table t) m 
  left join your_table t on t.server_time = c.dt and m.model = t.model
group by c.dt, m.model
```